# Problemas por ingresar, eliminar, añadir y actualizar una tabla usando PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb

Como es mi primera vez en este sitio y siendo nuevo en la comunidad de stackoverflow en español, he estado reaprendiendo php, pero... lo malo, es que nunca me funciona después de haber creado la prueba de conexión directa al PhpMyAdmin o sea directo al base de datos de SQL.

Añado los demás códigos y el sql. Espero que me puedan responder, estaré atento a sus respuestas, porque volver a reaprender el php me dificulta entender.

Muchos saludos estimados!

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 19-05-2017 a las 15:57:32
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `webpractica`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `estado`
--

CREATE TABLE `estado` (
  `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fecha_Creacion` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `estado`
--

INSERT INTO `estado` (`id_estado`, `Estado`, `Fecha_Creacion`) VALUES
(1, 'Completado', '2017-05-13'),
(2, 'Incompleto', '2017-05-13'),
(3, 'Analizado', '2017-05-13'),
(4, 'Bloqueado', '2017-05-13');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_estado`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  MODIFY `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

```html
<?php //pruebadeconexion.php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost");
mysql_select_db("webpractica", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_estado, estado, fecha_creacion FROM estado", $link);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<table border = '1'> \n";
echo "<tr><td>id_estado</td><td>estado</td><td>fecha_creacion</tr> \n";
do {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row["id_estado"]."</td><td>".$row["estado"]."</td><td>".$row["fecha_creacion"]."</td></tr>\n";
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 echo "</table> \n";
} else {
 echo "No se ha encontrado ningun registro!";
}
?> 
// Eso es lo que me había funcionado antes
```

```html
<?php //modifica.php
if (isset($id)) {
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost");
 mysql_select_db("webpractica", $db);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM estado WHERE id_estado=$id_estado";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $sql = "UPDATE agenda SET id_estado=$id_estado Estado='$estado', Fecha_Creacion=$fecha_creacion";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
} else {
 echo "Debe especificar un 'id_estado'\n";
}
?>
```

```html
<?php //borrado.php
if (isset($id)) {
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost");
 mysql_select_db("webpractica", $db);
 $sql = "DELETE estado WHERE id_estado=$id_estado";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
} else {
 echo "Debe especificar un 'id_estado'.\n";
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="anadir.php">
id_estado: <input type="Text" name="id_estado"><br>
Estado: <input type="Text" name="Estado"><br>
Fecha_Creacion: <input type="date" name=Fecha_Creacion><br>
<input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Aceptar información">
</form>

<?php // anadir.php
if (isset($enviar)) {
 // process form
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost");
 mysql_select_db("webpractica", $link);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO estado (id_estado, Estado, Fecha_Creacion) " + "VALUES($id_estado, '$Estado', $Fecha_Creacion)";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 echo "Recibido!\n";
} else { 
 
}
?>

// Esto es lo que he tratado de añadir una pequeña parte del html, pero aplicando con una mezcla con el código Php junto a MySql. Nunca me resultó.
```

P.D: Pregunta, en php con html y mysql se puede mezclar por las tablas?

Comment: Bienvenido @Baku84. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? No entiendo el sentido de **en php con html y mysql se puede mezclar por las tablas?**. ¿Qué mensaje de error tienes o qué problema te estás encontrando con todo ese código? Te animo a pasarte por [cómo preguntar (enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para documentarte acerca de cómo redactar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Muy buenos días. la ultima pregunta que dejé, me referia por el form method para establecer el envio de un registro con el formulario de proceso de MySql, es que estaba tratando de conectar el base de datos con una tabla específica, pero con los códigos que dejé, nunca me responden al tratar de insertar, eliminar y modificar un registro de la tabla (revisé constantamente phpmyadmin y no se ha pasado nada) de ahi es el error. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Baku84. ¿Podrías explicar mejor tu pregunta? Gracias.

Comment: Mi pregunta es: con el formato html, se permite añadir con php y mysql luego de la conexión al base de datos directa en phpmyadmin, usando la línea de comandos de mysql, se puede? saludos (igual expliqué un poco más los detalles en el segundo comentario (esta editado)), eso es lo que no comprendo del php que no me deja con sql.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir cómo se llama cada archivo que pegas en tu pregunta y darnos una breve aclaración de lo que intentas hacer, el error y lo que esperas conseguir? Sigo sin entender el problema. Además, estoy viendo que usas `register_globals` para que los campos del formulario se conviertan en variables. Esa práctica está completamente desaconsejada, igual que las funciones `mysql_*`. Deberías usar la variable súper global `$_POST` y PDO/mysql o mydqli.

Comment: editado por cada uno de los codigos (deberían verse los // como los nombres de los archivos mientras que el phpmyadmin es un base de datos del nombre practica y el otro que creé, es una tabla llamado estado) Mi mayor error es que los demás archivos como anadir, modifica y borrar.php no funcionan para conseguir lo que debo hacer: eliminar, anadir, agregar un registro de la tabla estado

Comment: Buenas @Baku84 para obtener tus resultados desde tu formulario `HTML`, debes utilizar el method `POST`, en tu sentencia (*anadir.php*) estas pasando variables de `PHP` que ni si quiera tienen algún valor, es decir, son `NULL`. Para obtener los resultados desde tu formulario `HTML` en `PHP` seria: `$id_estado = $_POST['id_estado'];` y así con el resto de `input` que quieras insertar en la `Base de Datos`. Una vez creado las variables con los datos correspondientes, podrás continuar con tu sentencia MySQL, aunque mejor como ya te han nombrado `PDO` o `MySQLi prepare`. .

Comment: Muy buenas. respondiendo a tu comentario, me acordaste de algo, puede que tengas razón, pero me pregunto sobre el form method, debe ser con nombre del mismo archivo html con php? aunque con el post se puede añadir igual la conexión al base de datos (aún esta el mysql_connect)? Espero su respuesta, saludos

Comment: Creo que comprendí un poco el código que recomendó @D.Bulten, no sé si hice correctamente la recompilación en conjunto con el include conexion2.php (conexión directa a base de datos) como puedo mostrar el codigo del php en los comentarios? Espero su respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a contestar a una parte de tu pregunta, para orientarte un poco y así podrás reescribir el resto del código.

Para obtener los datos desde tu formulario `HTML` en `PHP`, se utiliza la *super global* `$_POST['identificador_HTML']`, es decir, añadimos el *atributo* `name="identificador"`, en caso que usemos el `method="GET"`, utilizariamos la *super global* `$_GET['identificador']`.

> **Advertencia**
>   La extensión `Mysql*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

**Ejemplo**

*Formulario* **HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="anadir.php">
    id_estado: <input type="text" name="id_estado"><br>
    Estado: <input type="text" name="estado"><br>
    Fecha_Creacion: <input type="text" name="fecha" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid'); echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Aceptar información">
</form>
```

**anadir.php**

```
<?php

//Reseteamos variables PHP.
$msg = $id_estado = $estado = $fecha_actual = NULL;

//Comprobamos que este definido el formulario y no es NULL.
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    //Obtener datos desde formulario.
    $id_estado = $_POST['id_estado'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $fecha_actual = $_POST['fecha'];

    //Comprobamos que sean verdaderos los datos.
    if ($id_estado && $estado && $fecha_actual) {

        //Creamos conexión (Estilo por procedimientos).
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "contraseña", "webpractica");

        ///comprobar la conexión.
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        //Sentencia insertar.
        $query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO estado (id_estado, Estado, Fecha_Creacion) VALUES ('$id_estado','$estado','$fecha_actual')");
        //Comprobamos que se ejecuto correctamente nuestra sentencia.
        if (!$query) { #falso.
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        } else { #Verdadero.
            $msg = "Los datos se insertaron correctamente.";
        }
    }
}

//Respuesta PHP.
echo $msg;

?>
```

Alguna fuente que te puede ser de ayuda:
[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)
[PHP 5 Complete Form Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Lo hice correctamente por el formulario y el php que dejó (no hice copiar y pegar, solo escribiendo para entender), creo que ahora si comprendo bien! y debo leer los fuentes, creo que si necesitaré más comprensión, por último, leí lo de inyección de SQL, nunca supe eso la verdad! Creo que por ahora en adelante usaré sentencias mysqli prepare o PDO. Muchísimas gracias! Si tengo alguna pregunta sobre SQL o PHP, formularé una pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Me alegro @Baku84 que te haya servido, uno nunca deja de aprender, que tengas suerte en tu proyecto. Un saludo.

Comment: Tengo una consulta muy rara, que pasa en el caso de que la fecha_creacion pueda ser datetime? Eso es porque no me responde nada al tratar de añadir la fecha y la hora correcta del país (local)

Comment: @Baku84 Si, sería posible, podría quedar así `echo date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());` y revisa que tu columna *Fecha_Creacion* será de tipo `datetime` en tu Base de datos

Comment: en caso del php, debo añadir algo del query?  (igual fue hecho lo del echo date en html) y me aseguré que la tabla de Fecha_Creacion lleve datetime.

Comment: Creo que pillé un poco el problema, era cambiar el input type del html, es poner "datetime" para quedar igual al tabla donde lleva el tipo datetime

Comment: @Baku84 La *query* podria quedar tal cual. Tambien podrias quitar el *input* y lo haces directamente desde *PHP* creando una variable con dicho varlor y la añades a tu *query*.